# Fixing Poor Email

Tags: linux, email, spam, exim, dovecot

I'm having an issue with SenderBase. My IPs are not blocked in any BLs but people who use SenderBase/Ciscos stuff do not get my emails. Is this because my email system is setup poorly?

They list the following:

- Your email server or a computer in your network may be infected with malware and may be used to send spam.
- You may have an insecure
  network which is allowing other parties to use your network to send
  spam.
- Your email server may be misconfigured and might relay spam.
- You may be utilizing a dynamic IP that is not allowed to relay email
  directly to the Internet.

I have just my site running CPanel. As far as I know there is no spam or abuse. What should I check to ensure that the mail systems (Exim) are up to standards? I have the server pretty well configured so I just can't see the system being abused without me knowing it.

What standards should I be ensuring my e-mail server aligns up to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SenderBase, seemingly the two most important factors to their listings are:

1. SpamCop listings. Cisco reflect SpamCop's blocks within Senderbase, so read the best practices on SpamCop's sites and that will help you to avoid getting blocked this way - http://www.senderbase.org/help/blocked
2. As karthick mentioned, having reverse DNS setup correctly.

Once you've ensured RDNS is correct, you don't have SpamCop blocks and you follow email sending best practices (DKIM, SPF, abuse@ setup, signing up for feedback loops etc) you should be ok. Then it's down to the content of your emails, send volume and per domain (Yahoo, Hotmail, AOL etc) reputation monitoring and testing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your machine has attacked by hackers, they used to send spam through your server. Then, lookout your email configuration and restrict the inbound relay to your network. Also try to restrict your smtp connections through firewall.

Following will do better for your emailing infrastructure...

1. Don't set dynamic ips and it's not recommended for mailing activities. Instead use static IPs. Before getting static IPs, check their reputation in which it has blacklisted on any blacklistings such as MX-TOOLBOX, Senderscore, Senderbase,etc....
2. Setup SPF - which is a TXT record used for your IP authentication.
3. Setup DKIM - which is used for your domain authentication.
4. Setup rDNS for your domain.

After all maintain your reputation by sending consistent volume of mails.

Comment: 1) I know it is static
2) I'll double check sure it is set
3) same as 2
4) dont think that is set

Comment: setting up reverse dns is also must while setting up mail servers....